Additional loader to handle the result of these loaders: Nativescript app build issue
getting below error, when tried to upgrade project to node v20.12.2 & nativescript - 8.7.0 and run 'ns build android'
ERROR in ./node_modules/glob/node_modules/minimatch/dist/mjs/ast.js 188:11
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (188:11)
File was processed with these loaders:
* ./node_modules/@nativescript/webpack/dist/loaders/nativescript-worker-loader/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
return c;
 |     }
static #parseAST(str, ast, pos, opt) {
let escaping = false;
let inBrace = false;
 @ ./node_modules/glob/node_modules/minimatch/dist/mjs/index.js 3:0-31 823:19-31 987:0-31 987:0-31 991:16-19
 @ ./node_modules/glob/dist/cjs/src/index.js 4:20-62 42:18-60
 @ ./node_modules/glob-stream/index.js 7:11-26
 @ ./node_modules/vinyl-fs/lib/src/index.js 5:9-31
 @ ./node_modules/vinyl-fs/index.js 4:7-27
 @ ./node_modules/module/dist/index.js 23:15-34
 @ ./node_modules/mockery/mockery.js 37:8-25
 @ ./app/applications/test-helpers/nativescript-mocks.js 4:16-34
 @ ./app/ sync \.(xml%7Cjs%7C(?<%21\.d\.)ts%7Cs?css)$ ./applications/test-helpers/nativescript-mocks.js
 @ ./node_modules/@nativescript/webpack/dist/stubs/virtual-entry-typescript.js 3:16-103


webpack 5.88.1 compiled with 1 error and 2 warnings in 44504 ms
Webpack compilation complete.
Webpack details from package.json

"@nativescript/webpack": "5.0.16",
"webpack": "5.88.1",
"webpack-cli": "5.1.4",
"webpack-sources": "3.2.3

I tried to add this loader "import-glob-loader": "^1.1.0". But there was no change.
